# How to validate session token sent from client in Lambda with Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm using cognito to sign users into a web app. After sign in, a User object is returned with a session token, so far, so good. Now when this user sends a request to an API with a Lambda function attached to it, how can Lambda figure out whether the session token is legit and which user it belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Auth.signIn` method returns a `CognitoUser` object which has an access token in the field `user.signInUserSession.accessToken.jwtToken`. On the server, there exist different SDKs that can get the current user for this token. For Python and boto3 for example, this is done by

```
client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
client.get_user(AccessToken=token)
```

with `token` being the JWT token sent from the client.